# Check if a pointer is nil before instantiating

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C and I got really confused when I saw the `if` check in the getter of a property:

```
- (XXX)name {
    if (!_name) _name = [[XXX alloc] init];
    return _name;
}
```

Why do you have to check if the pointer is nil when instantiating? Isn't that all objects starts with 0(nil)? Why can't you just have the pointer point to the newly instantiated object on the left?

Comment: That's a common lazy-initialization pattern.  If it's nil, alloc and init the property's object.

Comment: While common, Lazy Initialization generally leads to pain and frustration.   For objects where the cost of instantiation doesn't really matter, just allocate in your initializer.   For objects where it does matter, lazy initialization just means you now have a performance or responsiveness issue that may likely be indeterminate in nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the point of this when you consider that `name` is called several times. The first call on a particular instance will allocate `_name`. In the subsequent calls `_name` wouldn't be `nil`, so the previously allocated item would be returned.

This is a lazy initialization pattern. This implementation is fine in single-threaded environments, and in environments where objects with this method are not shared among threads.

In concurrent environments you should use a thread-safe version of this pattern, which uses a lock, or the `dispatch_once` method.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you have to check if the pointer is nil when instantiating?

The second time you call the getter method, it's already instantiated. This pattern is used when you only want to instantiate the property once. If it's `nil` you haven't done it yet. If it's non `nil` just return the value.

> Isn't that all objects starts with 0(nil)?

Yep. If it's `nil` that means you need to instantiate it. So go ahead and do that, and from then on return that instance.

> Why can't you just have the pointer point to the newly instantiated object on the left?

Huh? I have no idea what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mini-pattern in Objective-C. You see it, for example, in custom property getters. The idea is to create an object, but only if you haven't created one before (and if you have, just return it). As @Nicholas Hart says in his comment, this also helps achieves lazy initialization (an object is created if and when it is referenced.

E.g.:

```
- (MyType *)myProperty
{
     if(!_myProperty)
    {
         _myProperty = [[MyType alloc] init];
    }
    return _myProperty;
}

// somewhere else, you want to use the property:
[self.myProperty doSomething];
```

In the call to `doSomething`, the getter method `myProperty` will be called, and the `_myProperty` ivar (which is behind the `myProperty` property) will be initialized, if necessary.